# I am looking for PDFs testing automation software

Tags: pdf, automation, software-testing, data

PDF Testing

1. Compare data from flat files to PDFs
2. Write logic to ensure PDF has correct data
3. Ensure there must be correct logos, bar codes, fonts, margin etc.

Please give me some recommendations

Comment: What is a "flat" file? What do you mean exactly by "correct data"?

Comment: The data is in excel file. I wanted to compare it with PDF data.  Currently, I am doing it manually (One by One). I am looking for a software that can automate this process.

Comment: How are the Excel and PDF files related? Was one generated from the other? Who made the two files? Can you provide an example pair? Are you looking to code+script this using libraries, or you are looking for a pre-packaged application that does it for you?

Comment: @Ryan
How are the Excel and PDF files related?
-Excel file has all the data and PDF has some of its data. I want to make sure that excel file's data matches to PDF.

Was one generated from the other?
-No, multiple files are used.

Who made the two files?
-Is it related to my question???

 I am looking for the PDF testing automation software but also open for other options. 

If you have any though or recommendation about Software/library, please feel free to suggest. thanks!